# wordpress plugin dev - 2 problems-no debug log. Plugin generated 1 character of unexpected

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm attempting my 1st wordpress plugin and am confused as to why Im getting the following error:

*

> The plugin generated 1 character of unexpected output during
> activation. If you notice “ headers already sent ” messages, problems
> with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
> this plugin.

- 

There are a lot of googles relating to this. Most state there are spaces somewhere.

I removed the example code copied from the wordpress site and now only have the initial comment block.  Still the same.

There are no lines before the <?php  or at the end of the file.  Some stated to remove or add the php close tag. Ive tried both.

The code now is :

```
 <?php
/**
* Plugin Name: 1jbtest
* Plugin URI: https://test.com/
* Description: JB  Experiment.
* Version: 0.1
* Author: JB
* Author URI: https://www.your-site.com/
* License: GPL2
**/
```

Thats is there is nothing else.

Im sorry I do not know how to add a screen shot.

In my wp-config.php Ive enabled DEBUG .

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

From what I can read there should be a debug file in the wp-content dir.
There is not.
I've checked perms on everything etc.

I realise this is really dumb. I'm lost, if it had code, I could do something but there is only a php tag and a comment. I have no clue how to debug a comment.
Thank You.

Comment: It appears that there is a space character before `<?php`

Comment: Hi,
Thank you, well done for spotting that one.
Its the old coding thing of a fesh pair of eyes sees the obvious when the person who wrote the code often misses it.
Thank you very much.
I guessed it had to be simple. After all there is not much there.

Do you have any suggestions why a debug log is seemingly not being produced ?
I've run finds on the whole tree.
Also run finds and greps in /var/log    
Thank you once again.